# Flickr module not showing any photos

Tags: 7

I am attempting to use the [Flickr module](http://drupal.org/project/flickr) 7.x-1.x-dev to display a block of recent photos from a photostream on Flickr. I have setup the API keys and correct user ID, but the block is not producing any output. I've checked the Drupal logs and can't see any issues. I've also run cron and cleared the cache.

Does anyone know how to get this module working or of any alternatives to this module that work in 7? I tried Flickrippr but it produced a lot of PHP errors that brought the site down.

Comment: ((1.)) You chose a `dev` version. Bugs should be expected. ((2.)) This sounds like a bug and should have been reported in the module's issue queue on [drupal.org](https://drupal.org). ((3.)) Asking for module recommendation is considered off-topic on Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the block *Flickr: User photos corresponding with a node's taxonomy term, location and/or date field* and under FILTER / SORT ORDER
leave *Flickr tags as node taxonomy terms (choose a vocabulary to use)* on *none*.

[image]

The sandbox demo at https://simplytest.me/project/flickr/7.x-1.x shows an example in the sidebar. Log in there and check the settings used with your own.

[image]